# Sharepoint /pages/page.aspx = good, /pages/ = access denied

Tags: .net, configuration, sharepoint-2007

So, we have a sharepoint install in three environments. In both dev and qa, we can do the following (after authentication):

://account.server.com/

In dev and qa, this redirects to
://account.server.com/somepage.aspx

In prod, this brings back 'access denied'.

Now, if I do this in production (after authentication):

://account.server.com/somepage.aspx

I'm in like Flint.

This screams a config or domain policy issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the welcome page url in the site (collection)'s site settings?